# Use Open CV in class library

Tags: c#, opencv, dll

I'm creating application using my own dll files in C#.

I would like to create Class Library which uses Open CV. I have to add reference to project - Emgu.CV.dll and Emgu.Util. It's ok but OpenCV needs also extra dll files for example "opencv_calib3d231.dll" and others. They have to be in Debug folder when I want to run some Projet using OpenCV.

But what if I want to use OpenCv in my own class library? Where do I have to put this extra dll files?

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a class library by itself: ultimately a class library will always (indirectly) be used by some executable program. You have to ensure that dependencies of your class library can be found by said executable, for example by putting them in the directory that executable is in.

So, if you have an executable project (Project A) and a class library (Project B) used by the executable project that has native dependencies like *opencv_calib3d231.dll*, it suffices to ensure the native dependencies are in Project A's directory at runtime.

If you are developing a class library that will be used by other developers in their programs, you should distribute the dependencies of your class library with the library (or at least provide instructions on how to obtain the dependencies in your documentation). They can then ensure the operating system can find the dependencies upon loading your class library.